# variable number of arguements RPC

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to know how to pass a variable number of arguments and types to an RPC function in UNITY?

I saw some similar questions asked in here  but no straight answers on how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RPC function is deprecated since unity 5.X cause a new network system was released. If you have an already made game and can't migrate from old network API you should take a look on [Legacy Network RPC's documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-RPCDetails.html), there is good covering information about how to pass params into RPCs.

Basicaly what you need is an array of objects like:

```
networkView.RPC("MyMethod",RPCMode.All, arg1[], arg2, arg...);
```

where args must match the end point method signature MyMethod(arg1[], arg2, arg...).

If you need declare methods with variable types and number of arguments you'll have a lot of ways to proceed (from using specific objects as arguments through convert or serialize an object as byte arrays or something that you would deserializes after receive ). You can improve your research results on this approaches by searching directly on "C#" instead of "Unity" or "RPC" targets...